# Checking in R whether a string is a substring in another column of longer length

Tags: r

I have two data sources / columns A & B, both having company names, possibly in a slightly different format. The data sources are of different sizes. For example:

A:

| Company |
| --- |
| Factory |
| Shop |
| Restaurant |

B:

| Company |
| --- |
| Factory Inc |
| Shop Ltd |
| Service |
| Laundry |

How could I look up row-wise, if A company exists, perhaps as a substring in a longer column in the data set B?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `sapply` and `str_detect`

```
sapply(df1$Company, function(x) str_detect(df2$Company, x))
```

```
     Factory  Shop Restaurant
[1,]    TRUE FALSE      FALSE
[2,]   FALSE  TRUE      FALSE
[3,]   FALSE FALSE      FALSE
[4,]   FALSE FALSE      FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which element of A is contained within which element of B, you can use the base function `grepl` with option `fixed = TRUE`. This option avoids unexpected behaviour if your text contains characters that are reserved in regular expressions, such as `.`, `?`, `(` or similar.

```
A <- c("Factory", "Shop", "Restaurant")
B <- c("Factory Inc", "Shop Ltd", "Service", "Laundry")
sapply(A, \(string) grepl(string, B, fixed = TRUE))

     Factory  Shop Restaurant
[1,]    TRUE FALSE      FALSE
[2,]   FALSE  TRUE      FALSE
[3,]   FALSE FALSE      FALSE
[4,]   FALSE FALSE      FALSE
```

However, if you only want to know if a row in A is present *anywhere* in B, you can add `any` to the expression...

```
sapply(A, \(string) any(grepl(string, B, fixed = TRUE)))
   Factory       Shop Restaurant 
      TRUE       TRUE      FALSE
```

...or you can "cheat" by turning B into one big string (potentially using `unique` to account for duplication). Use a separator that would not be present elsewhere to avoid creating new "words" at the boundaries.

```
Bcheck <- paste(unique(B), collapse="|")
Bcheck
[1] "Factory Inc|Shop Ltd|Service|Laundry"

sapply(A, \(string) grepl(string, Bcheck, fixed = TRUE))
   Factory       Shop Restaurant 
      TRUE       TRUE      FALSE
```

The latter is a bit faster according to microbenchmark.